# Unable to install KB4019990

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, visual-studio, .net-framework, dll

Software on my computer that uses the .NET Framework (PAINT.NET and the Visual Studio 2017 installer) is crashing on start up with the error message:

```
The program can't start because D3DCOMPILER_47.dll is missing from your computer.
Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

Despite having Service Pack 1 installed, when I try to install KB4019990 (as per [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020302/the-net-framework-4-7-installation-is-blocked-on-windows-7-windows-ser)), I get the error:

```
The update is not applicable to your computer.
```

Note:

- I first discovered the problem in September when trying to run PAINT.NET, but I only attempted to fix it with KB4019990 on the 5th of November.
- One thing that could be relevant is that the installation of KB4041681 failed and is not listed as being installed. This update, however, was after when I first discovered the issue.
- I managed to fix the issue with PAINT.NET by finding an old version of d3dcompiler_47.dll on my computer and copying it into the PAINT.NET install directory.
- I do not have any copies (old or new) of d3dcompiler_47.dll under %windir%\system32\

Comment: You are sure neither of these updates have been superceeded by another update.  Service Pack 1 was released years ago.  What is the file version of this file. Patches are strange if the file being updated isn’t a match then it could be blocking the update

Comment: I don't think KB4019990 has been superceeded as [this link](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb4019990) does not list any patches as replacing it for Windows 7 x64. According to [this](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb4041681) no updates replace KB4041681 for Windows 7 x64. The random version of d3dcompiler_47.dll I found on my computer is version 6.3.9600.16428. Should I copy the random copy of the file into %windir%\system32\ and then try to install either KB4041681 or reinstall a previous update that was supposed to update this file?

Comment: I am pretty sure the current version of the file before the patch is  6.3.9600.18611 because it should have a date of April 2017 and the file version will be something else after the patch your trying to install.

Comment: I've checked all versions of d3dcompiler.dll on my computer and none are 6.3.9600.18611. Should I get a copy of d3dcompiler.dll from a friend who has Windows 7?